# "npx cypress-ntlm open" Cypress is not loading

Tags: plugins, cypress

I am using the cypress-ntlm-auth plugin with cypress (behind a corporate proxy) but got the following issue:

**"NPM Cypress Open"** works perfect. Cypress is opening and I can run my tests.

**"npx cypress-ntlm run"**  works also perfect I can confirm that the ntlm connection is authorized.

But when I try ***"npx cypress-ntlm open"*** cypress is trying to start and it goes not further than the spinning CY logo.

[image]
Node v21.6.0
npm v10.3.0
Cypress 13.6.3 (also tried with 13.4.0)
LOGS:

```
PS C:\Git\xx\ClientApp> npx cypress-ntlm open
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth Adding localhost to NO_PROXY to disable localhost proxying +0ms
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth Adding 127.0.0.1 to NO_PROXY to disable loopback proxying +1ms 
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth Starting ntlm-proxy... +0ms
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth NTLM auth config API listening on: http://127.0.0.1:54263 +10ms
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth NTLM auth proxy listening on : http://127.0.0.1:54264 +15ms
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth Startup done! +0ms
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth {
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth   configApiUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:54263',
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth   ntlmProxyUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:54264'
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth } +0ms
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth Opening Cypress... +3ms
    
    
    DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54265/devtools/browser/5c6b6e7b-5df2-4561-a413-af9a686bff6b
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth getTargetHost - host header  localhost:54266 +1s
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth Created agent for client 127.0.0.1:54267 to target http://localhost:54266/ +18ms
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth Request to http://localhost:54266/ - pass on +12ms
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth getTargetHost - host header  localhost:54266 +368ms
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth getTargetHost - host header  localhost:54266 +231ms
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth Request to http://localhost:54266/ - pass on +23ms
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth getTargetHost - host header  localhost:54266 +3ms
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth Created agent for client 127.0.0.1:54269 to target http://localhost:54266/ +73ms
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth Request to http://localhost:54266/ - pass on +52ms
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth getTargetHost - host header  localhost:54266 +58ms
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth getTargetHost - host header  localhost:54266 +84ms
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth Tunnel to localhost:54266 +755ms
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth getTargetHost - host header  localhost:54266 +28ms
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth Request to http://localhost:54266/ - pass on +0ms
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth getTargetHost - host header  localhost:54266 +4ms
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth Tunnel to localhost:54266 +25ms
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth getTargetHost - host header  localhost:54266 +4ms
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth Request to http://localhost:54266/ - pass on +0ms
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth getTargetHost - host header  registry.npmjs.org:80 +829ms
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth Created agent for client 127.0.0.1:54277 to target https://registry.npmjs.org:80/ +3ms
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth Request to https://registry.npmjs.org:80/ - pass on +0ms
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth:tunnelagent [0]: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=403 +0ms
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth getTargetHost - host header  download.cypress.io:80 +361ms
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth Created agent for client 127.0.0.1:54281 to target https://download.cypress.io:80/ +9ms
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth Request to https://download.cypress.io:80/ - pass on +7ms
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth:tunnelagent [1]: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=403 +60ms
    "npx cypress-ntlm open"  cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth getTargetHost - host header  localhost:54266 +2s
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth Removed agent for 127.0.0.1:54267 due to socket.close +2s
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth getTargetHost - host header  localhost:54266 +991ms
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth Request to http://localhost:54266/ - pass on +0ms
    cypress-ntlm-auth: Certificate validation failed for "download.cypress.io:80". ETIMEDOUT
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth WARN: Certificate validation failed for "download.cypress.io:80". AggregateError [ETIMEDOUT]: 
        at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1116:18)
        at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1680:7) {
      code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
      [errors]: [
        Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.22.11.239:80
            at createConnectionError (node:net:1643:14)
            at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1702:38)
            at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
            at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
          errno: -4039,
          code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
          syscall: 'connect',
          address: '104.22.11.239',
          port: 80
        },
        Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.22.10.239:80
            at createConnectionError (node:net:1643:14)
            at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1702:38)
            at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
            at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
          errno: -4039,
          code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
          syscall: 'connect',
          address: '104.22.10.239',
          port: 80
        },
        Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 172.67.25.250:80
            at createConnectionError (node:net:1643:14)
            at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1673:16) {
          errno: -4039,
          code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
          syscall: 'connect',
          address: '172.67.25.250',
          port: 80
        }
      ]
    } +17s
    cypress-ntlm-auth: Certificate validation failed for "registry.npmjs.org:80". ETIMEDOUT
      cypress:plugin:ntlm-auth WARN: Certificate validation failed for "registry.npmjs.org:80". AggregateError [ETIMEDOUT]: 
        at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1116:18)
        at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1680:7) {
      code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
      [errors]: [
        Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.27.34:80
            at createConnectionError (node:net:1643:14)
            at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1702:38)
            at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
            at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
          errno: -4039,
          code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
          syscall: 'connect',
          address: '104.16.27.34',
          port: 80
        },
        Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.0.35:80
            at createConnectionError (node:net:1643:14)
            at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1702:38)
            at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
            at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
          errno: -4039,
          code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
          syscall: 'connect',
          address: '104.16.0.35',
          port: 80
        },
        Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.30.34:80
            at createConnectionError (node:net:1643:14)
            at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1702:38)
            at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
            at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
          errno: -4039,
          code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
          syscall: 'connect',
          address: '104.16.30.34',
          port: 80
        },
        Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.24.34:80
            at createConnectionError (node:net:1643:14)
            at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1702:38)
            at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
            at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
          errno: -4039,
          code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
          syscall: 'connect',
          address: '104.16.24.34',
          port: 80
        },
        Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.3.35:80
            at createConnectionError (node:net:1643:14)
            at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1702:38)
            at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
            at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
          errno: -4039,
          code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
          syscall: 'connect',
          address: '104.16.3.35',
          port: 80
        },
        Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.26.34:80
            at createConnectionError (node:net:1643:14)
            at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1702:38)
            at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
            at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
          errno: -4039,
          code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
          syscall: 'connect',
          address: '104.16.26.34',
          port: 80
        },
        Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.25.34:80
            at createConnectionError (node:net:1643:14)
            at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1702:38)
            at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
            at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
          errno: -4039,
          code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
          syscall: 'connect',
          address: '104.16.25.34',
          port: 80
        },
        Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.2.35:80
            at createConnectionError (node:net:1643:14)
            at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1702:38)
            at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
            at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
          errno: -4039,
          code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
          syscall: 'connect',
          address: '104.16.2.35',
          port: 80
        },
        Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.28.34:80
            at createConnectionError (node:net:1643:14)
            at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1702:38)
            at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
            at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
          errno: -4039,
          code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
          syscall: 'connect',
          address: '104.16.28.34',
          port: 80
        },
        Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.31.34:80
            at createConnectionError (node:net:1643:14)
            at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1702:38)
            at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
            at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
          errno: -4039,
          code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
          syscall: 'connect',
          address: '104.16.31.34',
          port: 80
        },
        Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.29.34:80
            at createConnectionError (node:net:1643:14)
            at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1702:38)
            at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
            at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
          errno: -4039,
          code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
          syscall: 'connect',
          address: '104.16.29.34',
          port: 80
        },
        Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.1.35:80
            at createConnectionError (node:net:1643:14)
            at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1673:16) {
          errno: -4039,
          code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
          syscall: 'connect',
          address: '104.16.1.35',
          port: 80
        }
      ]
    } +2s
```